Distorted load voltage with IR2110 for BLDC's ESC
I am trying to build an ESC for my BLDC.
I am currently using this schema, built on a breadboard for my first prototype:

For testing purposes, I am not using the motor as load, but using leds instead. When wiring everything up together, light switch is correct and seems to be working fine.
I used an oscilloscope to be sure that its works as expected.
I use ~20 V as input (instead of 36 V).
I am wiring green to low side MOSFET's gate (volProbe1 on schema), and yellow to Load (volProbe2 on schematic).
I was expecting something close to a square signal for the yellow, but I am having those two behaviours (I can figure out why it changes over time):


Why the yellow signal is not a square signal ? What is happening? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help

Are you using PWM more that 5 kHz ? It seems that you are using ~10 ms cycle. Too low frequency.

Probe Vs and Ho at the same time. As Antonio says, you are probably depleting your bootstrap capacitor due to too low frequency.

I raised the frequency to be above 5kHz.
Here are the mesures for VS (yellow) and HO(green) at the same time.
Any idea on what's happening ? How to make it a proper square signal ?
Thanks for your help
https://i.sstatic.net/yrFmXrA0.jpg
